how to select matching polygons?

There are two Objects:
1.Landscape
2.Cliff with landscape
Polygons of both +- along the roadside coincide (as you can see in the picture)
I would like to be able to select these matching polygons so I can delete them.
How can this be done within the Blender framework?
Maybe there is an addon of some sort.
Or is it only in geometric nodes to climb?





Coincide and match in what way precisely? No idea what you are talking about, but see Shift+G Select Similar menu - maybe they match in one of those ways available there?..

How Knife project do if you select 1 object and a second object. He after applying it selects all the polygons that he projected and everything inside, I need the same thing, but without Knife Project, so that he selected the polygons that match. In my picture you can see 2 geometries with matching polygons, but they are 2 different geometries, not stitched together, so select similar will not work for me.

Are you talking about overlapping geometry? I can't really see anything in the image you shared, it's not clear what it is there. Maybe you could share some more screenshots or the .blend file?

Attached pictures on a simpler example. I need that when selecting two objects, I can get the result as on photo 4 and 5

You can make a Geometry Nodes tool to select by proximity of another geometry:

Don't forget to enable it for edit mode:

